# Typescript TypeORM ManyToMany circular dependency?

Tags: typescript, many-to-many, circular-dependency, node.js-typeorm

I have the following entities. `Student` can subscribe to many `Teacher`s and `Teacher` can have many `Student`s.

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate } from "typeorm"
/*
* Use Data Mapper pattern: https://typeorm.io/active-record-data-mapper
*/
export abstract class EntityBase {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number
    @Column()
    public created: Date
    @Column()
    public modified: Date
    @BeforeInsert()
    updateDates () {
        this.created = new Date();
        this.modified = new Date();
    }
    @BeforeUpdate()
    updateModifiedDate () {
        this.modified = new Date();
    }
}
```

```
import { Entity, Column, ManyToMany, JoinTable } from "typeorm"
import { EntityBase } from "./EntityBase"
import { Teacher } from "./Teacher"
@Entity()
export class Student extends EntityBase {
    @Column({ length: 256 })
    public firstName: string

    @Column({ length: 256 })
    public lastName: string

    @Column({ unique: true, length: 256 })
    public email: string

    @Column()
    public isSuspended: boolean

    @ManyToMany((type) => Teacher, (teacher) => teacher.students)
    @JoinTable()
    public teachers: Teacher[]

    constructor(first: string, last: string, email: string, isSuspended?: boolean) {
        super();
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.email = email;
        this.isSuspended = isSuspended ?? false;
        this.teachers = [];
    }
}
```

```
import { Entity, Column, JoinTable, ManyToMany } from "typeorm"
import { EntityBase } from "./EntityBase"
import { Student } from "./Student"
@Entity()
export class Teacher extends EntityBase {
    @Column({ length: 256 })
    public firstName: string

    @Column({ length: 256 })
    public lastName: string

    @Column({ unique: true, length: 256 })
    public email: string

    @ManyToMany((type) => Student, (student) => student.teachers)
    @JoinTable()
    public students: Student[]

    constructor(first: string, last: string, email: string) {
        super();
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.email = email;
        this.students = [];
    }
}
```

Wouldn't this cause result in circular loading? How to improve or prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't cause circular dependency error.
`class` has two faces (as a type, as a value).
The types of Teacher and Student are circular referenced each other.
But as values (const), They are not referenced each other on loading time (imported timing).
It is achieved by delay value reference like `(type) => Teacher`.

teacher: Teacher; // this Teacher is a type. No problem in circular refecences.

() => Teacher; // this Teacher is a value (const). It causes problem if you use Teacher directly (instead of delay function).